# Submitting an older version of a file to Word Automation Services

Tags: office-integration, word

I'm able to obtain the URL to a specific version of a file.  I would like to submit that URL to WAS to convert.  However, WAS throws an exception:

**List does not exist.
The page you selected contains a list that does not exist.  It may have been deleted by another user.**

My sample url is:
http://win-7v2cj24h9bk:31835/_vti_history/1024/Lists/Docs/test/AFI-Doc1.docx

However, when I submit this url, WAS works just fine:
http://win-7v2cj24h9bk:31835/Lists/Docs/test/AFI-Doc1.docx

Thank you for any assistance anyone can offer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely familiar with WAS, but based on that test, I'd say that the past version needs to first be published as a major varsion then pushed to WAS.

Comment: Thank you PirateEric.  The specific example I have is the latest published version.  The current version is 2.1 which is the second url that works.